# error C2664: 'int printf(const char *const ,...)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'void' to '...'

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

void convert(std::stack<char> &s, int n,int base)
{
    static char digit[]={
            '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'
    };
    while(n>0)
    {
        s.push(digit[n%base]);
        n/=base;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::stack<char> s;
    int n=89;
    int base=2;
    convert(s,n,base);
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        printf("%c",s.pop());//this line is can not be compiled.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I do not understand why this line can not be compiled.

> Cannot pass expression of type 'void' to variadic function;expected type from format string was 'int'.

Comment: pop() does not return a value so nothing to print. you want to use s.top() to print and s.pop() to pop the top item off the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Check the signature of `std::stack::pop`: it returns void. You should use `top` to get the value and `pop` to remove it.

The corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

void convert(std::stack<char> &s, int n,int base)
{
    static char digit[]={
            '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'
    };
    while(n>0)
    {
        s.push(digit[n%base]);
        n/=base;
    }

}


int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::stack<char> s;
    int n=89;
    int base=2;
    convert(s,n,base);
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        printf("%c",s.top());
        s.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

General comment on your code: what if you provide a negative `n` to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printf s.pop use  printf s.top()
Then pop s as well, to take this element out of stack